# FATAL_ERROR System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151 is encountered when the test class is ran. Why?

Tags: queueable-apex

[image]

Queueable class code is down below:

```
public class AddPrimaryContact  implements Queueable{
    private Contact contacts;
    private String state;

    public  AddPrimaryContact(Contact records, String st){
        this.contacts= records;
        this.state = st;

    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context){
        List<Account> listAccount = [SELECT id,Name,(SELECT id,FirstName,LastName from Contacts) from Account where BillingState =: state limit 200];
        List<Contact> listContact = new List<Contact>();
        for (Account acc : listAccount){
            Contact cont = contacts.clone(false,false,false,false);
            cont.AccountId = acc.Id;
            listContact.add(cont);
        }
        insert listContact;
    }

}
```

The test class code is down below:

```
@isTest
public class AddPrimaryContactTest {

    @isTest public static void AddPrimaryContactTestMethod(){
        for (Integer i =0;i<200;i++){
            Account acc = new Account(Name='Doable',Rating = 'Hot');
            insert acc;
        }

        Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'Dona',Phone = '90284227003');
        insert con;

        String state= 'NY';

        Test.startTest();
        AddPrimaryContact apc = new AddPrimaryContact(con,state);
        System.enqueueJob(apc);
        Test.stopTest();
        //System.assertEquals(200,[select count() from Contact where accountID IN (SELECT id FROM Account WHERE BillingState = 'NY')]);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are making a dml statement inside a loop, you should gather the accounts and make single dml when possible

> AddPrimaryContactTest.cls
>
> ```
> ...
> for (Integer i =0;i<200;i++){
>     Account acc = new Account(Name='Doable',Rating = 'Hot');
>     insert acc; // not a good idea
> }
> ...
> ```

you should do something like ...

```
List<Account> accountsToInsert = new List<Account>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    accountsToInsert.add(new Account(Name='Doable', Rating = 'Hot'));
}
insert accountsToInsert;
```

This way you also make sure that the triggers on Account, etc are bulkified.

Comment: Looks good. But test classes code do not get counted towards governor limits,right? But if we are not bulkifying the code in  test class, it is throwing dml exception error. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Test classes are under governor limits (they do not commit the data though), you can "trick" the limits a bit using different contexts to restart the limits from 0, such as testSetup, startTest(), etc. But governor limits apply (otherwise imagine if you would deploy a testClass with `while(true){insert new Account();}`. That will stay there until the end of days ;)

Comment: Considering that I bulkified the code  under the loop  for (Integer i =0;i<200;i++) in the above test class .Will the DML exception be thrown still?

Comment: Only if in the same context you make more than 150 dmls . Inserting a list of 200 accounts in one statement call is 1 dml (+ whatever you trigger behind). VS what you had before, which was inserting 1 account 200 times that equals to 200 dmls (+ whatever you trigger behind) (for sure that hits the 150 limit)

Comment: Thanks Sergio. Appreciate your time.